# Scrolling in tmux over SSH (PuTTY)

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, putty, tmux

I'm SSH'ing into my RaspPi (Raspbian) with PuTTY and I want to user tmux in order not to worry about a connection ending while I'm installing something. My Problem is, that when I call `tmux` from a `bash` session and I scroll upwards, I don't see the previous lines of my `tmux` session, but of my plain `bash` session. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `screen` (similar to `tmux`) keeps its own scrollback buffer, and to browse it you have to use the method it defines. `tmux` probably has something similar. The reason you're not seeing the scrollback is because the text isn't really scrolling off the top of the screen when using these programs.

Comment: Yep, that's how it works. See linked duplicate question.

Comment: @Steve Yeah i figured that out already. But isn't there any way to "fix" this?

Comment: While I'm not familiar with `tmux`, it's very likely that you would have to modify that program the change its behavior, which is possible because it's open source.

Comment: When you "switch" to a different screen with `tmux`, where would that scroll-back data go for the other windows, since that scrollback buffer is maintained by your terminal emulator, and not the system you're connected to?